# Spring boot disable user

Tags: spring, boot

Good morning. Question scenario is as follows. Suppose an employee with a role goes to annual leave and he has an account in a spring boot application. How can I disable his user account so that logins fail at that time. How do I write the code? I'm using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter but I failed to accomplish this task. I need sample working code using preferably Spring boot 2.6.* cause other resources I found on the net are using older versions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by account is in spring application? How are you providing User info to Spring security for log-in?

Comment: By user account, I mean a user having a record in database user table. I don't know if I can post code here

Comment: No need to post code here but you must have provided user info through either query or by implementing UserDetailsService etc. That's what I am looking for

Comment: I implemented UserDetailsService interface. But in UserRepository there is another method @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email=?1  ")
   User findByEmail(String email); I don't know if it is in this method where I need to add another condition for instance adding that u.enabled = 1 or if it's in another method ? Your help is much needed

Comment: In the implementation of the loadUserByUsername method  of the UserDetailsService interface I call the previous method that is findByEmail(String email) to find if the user is present by the provided email. I don't see how I can stop those who have u.enabled=0 from logging in the application. login works fine, but when in Thymeleaf I try to display the logged in user using the expression ${#authentication.getPrincipal().getMail()} i get null

Comment: In UserDetailsService, when you provide user details, it contains several parameters like `public User​(java.lang.String username,
            java.lang.String password,
            boolean enabled,
            boolean accountNonExpired,
            boolean credentialsNonExpired,
            boolean accountNonLocked,
            java.util.Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities)` in this you can set accountNonLocked to false when user is on annual leave

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable a user for a certain period of time where the user can not log in till u enable his ID, then I assume that u created a table of name "User" where you store all user credentials, specify two more columns "role" and "isActive(boolean)", in "role" column you can specify your role as ADMIN or ROLE_ADMIN and write a code with logic where an admin has all authorization, as an admin you can alter the data, before that you should write a code for only active users can log in, then as an admin, you can change the state from "true" to "false" in the specific user's "isActive" column, now the user only able to login if his "isActive" state is true.

you can ping me any time...

Comment: Hi, Abhishek and thanks for your reaction. I have User table with field named "enabled" which is the equivalent of isActive you suggested i hope. Second, roles are saved in users_roles since it's a ManyToMany relationship between User and Role tables. Can u suggest me a working code please? I'm new to spring boot. Otherwise I agree with algorithm you're proposing.

Comment: I assume you created two entities User and Users_roles and mapped them with ManyToMany, it sounds like one user can have many roles.
Are you familiar with JPA and hibernate? because it will make your work easy.

Comment: I have User and Role in a ManyToMany Relationship that yields users_roles association table. I think i have enough required JPA knwoledge

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).